# Is, or should, comment reviewing be on-topic for this site?

Tags: support, scope

Source code commenting is essential to the maintainability, readability, and quality of code. Are reviews for such comments on-topic on this site? Alternatively, do we want these types of questions on this site?

Comment: Why do you think this wouldn't be ok? We've had people post answers about this for a long time, many of [the results of this search](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=docstring%20is%3aanswer) show a specific kind of comment, docstrings, get talked about a lot.

Comment: @Peilonrayz My point of concern is mostly about the **style and volcabulary** used in comments. These are **technical**, so I felt that English.SE (or Chinese, which is what my peers and I speak most natively, or any other language) aren't the best fit.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out English.SE, or Chinese.SE if it exists, if your question is technical. The Stack Exchange network has a lot of technical people even in non-technical communities. Depending on what you mean by "style and vocabulary" the skills the other sites have could very well be superior to Code Review.

Comment: Note, the 4th-highest voted answer is ONLY about the comments: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa

Answer (score 8):

These are called "source code comments" for a reason :)

The help center explicitly stated that "[any or all facets of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" are reviewable.
The code presented in the question still needs to fulfil the other conditions for being on-topic.

Notably that means it's not on-topic to ask a question that contains only comments, as those don't **do** anything. I don't see any reason to explicitly exclude comments from review.